# Ansible tower-cli on Windows 10 - tower-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, pip, ansible, ansible-tower

From this link: https://github.com/ansible/tower-cli/, you install tower-cli with pip install ansible-tower-cli but when you go to run a command like: `tower-cli config host www.myWebsite.com`,

You get this error: `tower-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 14-Sep-2016 15:41:49  operable program or batch file.`

I know that error means that ***I need to add the location of that executable to the windows PATH*** which I thought i did with:

[image]

But still same error, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the command python in your windows shell and get that error, 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or bathc file, then do this:

*Replace **python** with **py***, so type `py` in the command prompt and it'll work.

```
Again type "py" NOT "python" in your command prompt and it should work !
```